# MS OFFICE C#: Primary Interop Assemblies

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-pia

Any one know of a way to install MS Office Primary Interop Assemblies without installing having to install office itself?

Comment: So without Office installed, how are you testing?

Comment: you cannot, office has to be available on the client machine, Microsoft is not giving it to you or your users for free simply by copying some interop files around.

Comment: they won't work properly without an Office installation... what is the goal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, not possible, or useful. There is no sense installing libraries designed so you can interoperate with Office, if there is no Office to interoperate with. (Note, you need a full licence for whatever office product you are using trough Interop too).

Comment: A reasonable and common scenario is a build/CI server -- where the application is built, but will never run. Thus the interop assemblies are needed (for compilation) but an instance of Office is not.

Answer (score 3):

The use of this would be for setting up an automated build machine for continuous integration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Primary Interopr is only interop libraries - this is something like bridges between your application and Office dll's,

That is why to create word file, or any other functionality of MS Office, you will need to have installed Office.

Just think - if no, there will be millions of open source office applications which will be build on top of Interops:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Office Tools for Visual Studio](http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2013) (VSTO).

The assemblies will be installed here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA
```

Comment: link to an executable? was that... intentional?

Comment: You can find the link on this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2014/03/03/new-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-march-2014-update-news-in-sharepoint-development.aspx